# kendo grid sort after delete

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I made a simple grid (Which is **Sortable**) and added a few records in it . When i delete all records and then if i click on any column to sort it take all records back even though i delete all of them

Here is what i am doing

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
var dataitem = {};
var grid = $('#mygrid').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {data : [{
        status: 'On',
        description: 'a longer description'
    }, {
        status: 'On',
        description: 'a longer description'
    }, {
        status: 'On',
        description: 'a longer description'
    }, {
        status: 'On',
        description: 'a longer description'
    }, {
        status: 'On',
        description: 'a longer description'
    }, {
        status: 'On',
        description: 'a longer description'
    }]},
    width: 250,
    height: 200,
    sortable:true,
    columns: [{
        field: "status"
    }, {
        field: "description",
        title: "Description"
    }, {
        command: [{
            name: "delete",
            text: "delete",
            click: _handleDelete,
            imageClass: "ui-icon ui-icon-close"
        }],
        title: "&nbsp;",
        width: "100"
    }]
}).data('kendoGrid');

var kWindow = $('#window').kendoWindow({
    width: "500px",
    title: "Delete dialog",
    visible: false
}).data('kendoWindow');

$('.yesbtn').click(function () {
    console.log('My message');
    grid.dataSource.remove(dataitem);  
    kWindow.close();
});

$('.nobtn').click(function () {
    console.log('My other message');
    dataitem = {};
    kWindow.close();
});

function _handleDelete(event) {
    dataitem = grid.dataItem($(event.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    kWindow.open();
};
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtiik/KZ6pj/8/)

Comment: Call refresh on the datasource after the delete

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/KZ6pj/46/  I've just included the sortable property

Comment: its not working , delete all records then try to click sort it will show all deleted records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed that other peoples also facing same problem and that was a bug in library and they fixed in latest version . So, i just updated version and its fixed.